# How can I run multiple expressions inside of a list comprehension python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was trying to write a complex list comprehension but I am not sure how I am supposed to do it.
I have the following for loop which I am trying to turn into a list comprehension

```py
number = 10
deci_list = []

for i in sorted(list(range(9)), reverse=True):
    if 2**i <= number:
        deci_list.append(1)
        number -= 2**i
    else:
        deci_list.append(0)
```

I was struggling to turn this into a list comprehension and this is what I have so far:

```py
thing = sorted(list(range(9)), reverse=True)
new_thing = ['1' if 2**i <= number number -= 2**i else '0' for i in thing]
```

however, I do not know how to add the line `number -= 2**i` because it gives me an error every time I try to add it

```
    new_thing = ['1' if 2**i <= number number -= 2**i else '0' for i in t
hing]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: expected 'else' after 'if' expression
```

Comment: it is actually cleaner in a for loop.

Comment: also,  did you mean `number -= 2**i` (in the `if` statement) ??

Comment: Possible but not recommended method: `['1' if 2 ** i <= number and ((number := number - 2 ** i) or True) else '0' for i in reversed(range(9))]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're getting a syntax error due to the assignment, `=`, operator. It isn't supposed to be used in a list comprehension. Here's one way to work around the situation. Note that `sorted(list(range(9)), reverse=True)` could be replaced with `range(8, -1, -1)`.

```py
number = 10


def operator(index):
    global number

    if 2 ** index <= number:
        number -= 2 ** index
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


print([operator(index) for index in range(8, -1, -1)]) # Or: list(map(operator, range(8, -1, -1)))
```

Edit: As suggested by @ShadowRanger in the comment section, it is generally not a good idea to play with global variables in a function as it couples the two [essentially requiring you to reset the global variable or do something similar when you want to reuse the function]. You could wrap the two in a class to make it reusable.

**However**, I would recommend list comprehensions only at places where they do not compromise on readability. What you have in the original snippet is completely alright.

Comment: Even cleaner than `range(8, -1, -1)` to my mind is just the reversing slice, `range(9)[::-1]`; `range` supports that and produces a `range` equivalent to `range(8, -1, -1)`, just easier to read. `reversed(range(9))` also works, but who needs to type all those characters? :-) That said, writing a function that relies on a global like this is... suboptimal. It's basically a non-function; you can't use it without resetting the global variable. Typically you'd write a simple class in such a case, so the state was per-instance (and the same code could be used reentrantly, threaded, etc.).

Comment: I understand that this is suboptimal. Thanks for pointing out how a class would help! The overall intention was to recommend avoiding a list comprehension as no matter what you do, you're only going to write more code that required for the problem. I'll update my answer to cover the intention.